# Context Bound confusion

Tags: scala

When I declare `class Pair[T : Ordering]`, it requires that there is an implicit value of `Ordering[T]`. In the example below, I am trying to figure out where the implicit value of `Ordering[Int]` is coming from.

It looks like `scala.math.Ordering.Int` should be the implicit value here, but it has not been imported, so where is the implicit value being gotten from?

```
class Pair[T : Ordering](val first: T, val second: T) {
    def smaller(implicit ord: Ordering[T]) = 
        if(ord.compare(first, second) < 0) first else second
}

object Run extends App {
    val p = new Pair[Int](2, 3)
}
```

Comment: In Intellij you can find out what implicits are being called with command + shift + p (not sure about about other platforms, probably ctrl instead of command).

Comment: You should be aware that the Scala standard `Predef` includes an alias for `Pair[A, B] = Tuple2[A, B]`. It's usually a bad idea to shadow built-in types. There's also `Triple[A, B, C] = Tuple3[A, B, C]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf):

> The *implicit scope* of a type *T* consists of all companion modules
>   (§5.4) of classes that are associated with the implicit parameter’s
>   type.

The following quarter of a page defines what *associated with* means here, but the only part that matters for your question is that `Ordering` is associated with `Ordering[Int]`, so the compiler goes looking in [the companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordering%24) for `Ordering`, and sure enough, there's `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because Int is implicitly enriched with Ordered trait:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/implicit-classes.html

Comment: The compiler would eventually get to this implicit, but it hits `Ordering.Int` first. We can tell this by printing `implicitly[Ordering[Int]].toString`, which will be `scala.math.Ordering$Int$blahblah` instead of `scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits$$anon$blahblah`.